# PHP preg_replace: Replace All Hyphens in String That Appear Before the Last Hyphen w/ Space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

Using preg_replace (or other PHP-based option): I need to replace all hyphens in a string, **that appear before the last hyphen**, with space.

**Example #1 of the Result I Need:**

string = My-Cool-String - 201

result = My Cool String - 201

**Example #2 of the Result I Need:**

*Note: Notice that this string example only contains 1 hyphen.*

string = My Cool String - 201

result = My Cool String - 201

My current code is stripping out ALL hyphens and replacing with space.

```
$origString = 'My-Cool-String - 201';
$newString = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", ' ', $origString);
```

Additional Context:

In the example string of `My Cool String - 201`

*My Cool String* represents the name of a resort.

*201* represents the room number.

I was running into my originally stated issue when the name of the resort contained hyphens.

Comment: explode pop implode … https://3v4l.org/1uj7A

Comment: @Cid Technically, within the system that we use, there should never be an instance like `My-Cool-String-201` However, in that event, the output should be `My Cool String - 201`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('/-(?=.* -)/', ' ', $origString)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ugqQE) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLQWKj/1). To account for any whitespace use `'/-(?=.*\s-)/'`, or `'/-(?=.*\s-\s)/'` (if there should be whitespaces on both sides of the hyphen).

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=.* -)` - a positive lookahead that requires  `-` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (use `s` flag after `/` to match across line breaks).

Comment: @Cid That is not what OP needs. Also, you are thinking up test cases that OP confirms won't occur in their system.

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to be sure